# Trying to migrate an imported EKS cluster from one Rancher cluster to another

Tags: kubernetes, migration, amazon-eks, rancher

General overview:

- I have an on-prem Rancher deployment running 2.6.6 and a cloud hosted Rancher deployment running 2.7.3.
- I have some kube clusters on the on-prem deployment that are Rancher created (I know these are going to be much more challenging and not the scope of this question) and some kube clusters that are imported.
- My question is around the imported kube clusters and essentially importing them into the cloud hosted deployment.

Everything that I've found so far says that this is simply an import of an existing cluster, however once I get the cluster set up as pending on the new Rancher (have not run the kubectl to grant access yet) I get the following warning:

You should not import a cluster which has already been connected to another instance of Rancher as it will lead to data corruption.

Is this referring to clusters created in the previous Rancher, or any cluster that has ever been connected to a different Rancher deployment? If it is, does that leave the only possible recourse performing a backup and restore? What are some complications I could expect?

So far I've researched the case and have not found a sufficiently reassuring answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed referring to any cluster that has ever connected to a rancher setup. If you're only trying to move selected clusters from one rancher setup to another, I don't think there's a well documented way to do this outside of contacting rancher support. There are certain annotations and finalizers on rancher and/or the imported clusters that you would need to manually find and remove.

However if you want everything moved over, you could follow these migration [steps from rancher docs.](https://ranchermanager.docs.rancher.com/how-to-guides/new-user-guides/backup-restore-and-disaster-recovery/migrate-rancher-to-new-cluster)